# how can i get the value of array

Tags: xml, arrays, loops, simplexml

i want to get all the values on "ListNumber", how can i loop it using php? thanks in advance :)

```
   [ListNumbersList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Record] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [Returned] => 1
            )

        [ListNumber] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 4
                [4] => 5
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach($listNumberList->Listnumber as $value)
echo $value;

try this one